# PHP multiple select form to insert multiple rows in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code used to insert a record using PHP into a MySQL database.  The form element is a multiple select that works fine when only one option is selected.  When I choose more than 1 option, only the last option is inserted.  How do I have the form create a new row for each option selected in the multiple select?

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "InsertForm")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO emplikons (EmpNo, IconId) VALUES (%s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['insertRecordID'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['icons'], "int"));

  mysql_select_db($database_techsterus, $techsterus);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $techsterus) or die(mysql_error());
```

This is the code of the form element.  It uses a recordset to dynamically pull values from another table:

```
<select name="icons" size="10" multiple="multiple">
            <?php
do {  
?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row_icons['id']?>"><?php echo $row_icons['name']?></option>
            <?php
} while ($row_icons = mysql_fetch_assoc($icons));
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($icons);
  if($rows > 0) {
      mysql_data_seek($icons, 0);
      $row_icons = mysql_fetch_assoc($icons);
  }
?>
          </select>
```

Comment: Can you add the code of your form, especially the multi-select input?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @thaJeztah , question is updated now.  thanks.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum thanks for the info, I will check it out and see about stopping using it, appreciate the links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add `[]` to the name of the select, to get an array of all selected values.

```
<select name="icons[]" size="10" multiple="multiple">
```

Then, read from `$_POST / $_GET`... (assuming `form method="post"`)

```
$sql = '';
foreach ($_POST['icons'] as $icon) {

    // no idea where to get EmpNo from, let's assume it is in $empno.
    $sql .= "('$empno','$icon'),";

}

$sql = "INSERT INTO tablename (EmpNo, IconId) VALUES " . trim($sql,',');

// Now, please use mysqli_* or PDO instead of mysql_*
```

Comment: However, you'll also have to update the insert query, because the current query will only insert a single row

Comment: @michi EmpNo is a session variable but I get a 500 server error when I insert that it like this:   $row_WADAsess['EmpNo']

Is it because of the 'EmpNo'?  How do I escape that?

Comment: @RoccoTheTaco: what about $_SESSION['nameofvariable']??

Comment: OH MY, duh! I feel like a dummy LOL...perfect, worked great.  Thanks so much!