# PHP MySQL Inserting multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, forms

Good evening lovely people,

I'm having problems with my query. The query should insert each product which is entered on the page. My table **products** has 4 fields: id, product_name, quantity and price.

The HTML looks a bit like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">

    Product name: <input type="text" name="product_name[]" value="" />
    Quantity: <input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="" />
    Price: <input type="text" name="price[]" value="" /> <br /> <br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Insert new products" />

</form>
```

I want my users to be able to insert new products into our database table **products**. By the way, I've created a javascript function which adds more fields to the form so my employees do not have to submit the form every time he or she wants to add a new product, but instead just add as many fields he or she needs to submit. Hopefully you'll know what I am talking about :)

Since I am not an expert in PHP coding, then I've tried on my own, which in my case has not worked particularly well. Of course I've been reading some articles on the web about querying array data, but with no luck, sadly.

So far, the PHP code looks like this:

```
<?
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $product_name = addslashes($_POST['product_name']);
    $quantity     = addslashes($_POST['product_name']);
    $price        = addslashes($_POST['product_name']);

    $db->query("INSERT INTO products (product_name, quantity, price) VALUES ('".$product_name."', '".$quantity."', '".$price."')");
}
?>
```

If my employees have to insert each product one by one this had not been a problem. But since they can add more fields to the form then it becomes a problem.

Hopefully there is a logical explanation, but I can not figure it out on my own. And of course I am aware that I have not escaped my variables but this code is just for testing purposes. Have a good evening folks :)

Comment: `addslashes` is a quite weak form of protection against SQL Injection.

Comment: Your `$_POST` data is an array - you'll need to iterate over it, so best to look up [`for()`](http://www.php.net/for) or [`foreach()`](http://www.php.net/foreach)

Comment: You can look for tutorials on inserting data from multiselects, which is very similar to what you're attempting. See for example, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15509742/php-multiple-select-form-to-insert-multiple-rows-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop through all values in the array `$_POST['product_name']` and issue a DB insert query once for each member of the array. The form data for each field set is submitted and processed as an array in PHP, like:

> $_POST['product_name'] = array(  0 => 'first name',  1 => 'second
>   name',  2 => 'third name',  etc. )

Here's the code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $ct=0;
    foreach( $_POST['product_name'] as $k=> $value ){ // loop through array
        $product_name = addslashes( $value );  // set name based on value
        $quantity     = addslashes($_POST['quantity'][$ct] ); // set qty using $ct to identify # out of total submitted
        $price        = addslashes($_POST['price'][$ct] ); // same as set qty

        $db->query("INSERT INTO products (product_name, quantity, price) VALUES ('".$product_name."', '".$quantity."', '".$price."')");
        $ct++; // increment +1
    }
}
```

To UPDATE (not INSERT) you need to pass an ID number along with the input fields in your HTML.

```
<input type="hidden" name="modify_id[]" value="7" />
Product name: <input type="text" name="product_name[]" value="" />
Quantity: <input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="" />
Price: <input type="text" name="price[]" value="" /> <br /> <br />
```

Then using PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $ct=0;
    foreach( $_POST['product_name'] as $k=> $value ){ // loop through array
        $product_name = addslashes( $value );  // set name based on value
        $quantity     = addslashes($_POST['quantity'][$ct] ); // set qty using $ct to identify # out of total submitted
        $price        = addslashes($_POST['price'][$ct] ); // same as set qty

        $id           = (int)$_POST['modify_id'][ $ct ];

        $db->query("UPDATE products SET product_name = '$product_name', quantity = '$quantity', price = '$price' WHERE id = '$id' LIMIT 1");
        $ct++; // increment +1
    }
}
```

Comment: A valid point. You could substitute `$k` for all instances of `$ct` for the other arrays, and remove the `$ct=0;` and `$ct++;` lines. But, I think, the data in `$k` is string, not integer.

Comment: And how will this work for updating the current fields in one page?

Comment: This will loop multiple times, for each set of fields you've added in the JavaScript. So if there are 8 sets of 3 fields, it will loop over them and submit 8 times.

Comment: `$k` is an integer so it would be safe and appropriate to use as a counter. Even if it wasn't, the arrays are all put together by PHP so those array elements would be all ordered by the same character type anyways.

Comment: I see. The code are working just fine thanks! But I really can't figure out how to update the current fields or rows in the database in just one page. It just overwrites every single field in the table..

Comment: What do you mean when you say "overwrites every single field in the table"? Do you mean in the database table? I think your database table might need some PRIMARY UNIQUE key, so as to keep track properly.

Comment: Yes, I mean the database table. I've got a field called invoice_nr which is unique for the selected Invoice, and then of course the id of every row in the db table

Comment: Nothing in your code above to insert should overwrite or eliminate any other records in the table. Are you executing other queries somewhere?

Comment: No, I mean if I want to create another page, instead of inserting then updating the current rows in the database, how should the query be looking like then? I want it to be just the same as when I'm inserting. Multiple input fields with all the product for that specific invoice number. I've tried on my own, but every time I going to run the query, then it's overwriting every row with that invoice_nr. Sorry for the misunderstanding :)

Comment: oooh I see what you mean! I'll update my answer to show because the code will be a little lengthy.

Comment: Thanks man! I will definitely try this tomorrow. I am most grateful for your amazing help :) take care man!